# Reduce resolution in captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:

Tags: macos, avfoundation, webcam, avcapturesession

I'm trying to use a smaller resolution when getting access a webcam video feed, I need to do fast editing when it comes down to previewing. Currently when the image is being outputted from the sample buffer the resolution comes out as 1600x1200 which is too high for what I want to do with it

When setting up the session I use this which it accepts, however regardless of this is does not seem that the changes are being made

```
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
if ([_session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240])
{
    [_session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240];
}
```

One other thing I will also need the webcam to take full size images using `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:`, this is currently fine